# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in Python3.6.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, byte, typeerror

I am new to python...I've very recently migrated to Py 3.6.8. This code was working properly in Python 2.7:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import json
import sys
import os
import re
import subprocess
import datetime
from glob import glob
import boto3

class VariableCollector:
  def getall(self):
    collected_vars = {}
    for name in dir(self):
      #name = name.decode()
      if name.startswith("get_"):
        debug("VariableCollector - Calling: %s" % (name))
        method = getattr(self, name)
        collected_vars[name] = method()
        collected_vars[name + ":no_quotes"] = collected_vars[name].replace("'","")

        debug("Function: [%s] Value: [%s]" % ( name, collected_vars[name] ))
    return collected_vars
```

After upgrading to 3.6.8, I'm getting the:

```
  File "./process.py", line 21, in getall
    collected_vars[name + ":no_quotes"] = collected_vars[name].replace("'","")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: `name = name.decode()` it convert bytes to string using `UTF-8` on most systems. You can also uses `.decode("utf-8")` to make sure that it uses `UTF-8`. Or you can uses other encoding if data are ind different encoding - ie. `.decode("cp1250")`

Comment: Thanks @furas for replying: I tried using ```name = name.decode()``` but i received the error ```File "./process.py", line 16, in getall
    name = name.decode()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'```

Comment: so it means that different element is a bytes (not `name`). Use `print(...)` and `print(type(...))` to check which element is bytes. Maybe `collected_vars[name]` is a bytes - `print(type(collected_vars[name]))` And then you would have to use `.decode()` with `collected_vars[name]`.

Comment: same with ```File "./process.py", line 16, in getall
    name = name.decode("utf-8")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'```

Comment: as I said before - bytes doesn't have to be in `name` but `collected_vars[name]` and you may need `collected_vars[name] = collected_vars[name].decode()`. Use `print(type(collected_vars[name]))` to check it.